# Running CouchDB with SSL stops working

Tags: ssl, openssl, couchdb, mochiweb

I have a Couchapp running on a CouchDB instance.  I have enabled SSL following the instructions on the Wiki http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_enable_SSL using a signed certificate Entrust.  I can access my application using SSL, however I keep getting occasional errors.

Occasionally my browser shows an error saying "SSL received an unexpected Handshake record.

(Error code: ssl_error_rx_unexpected_handshake)".

Additionally, my application subscribes to the _changes API in order to keep all clients up to date.  This works great for the first few minutes I have the application open, but after about 3-5 minutes it stops working.  Any changes the client tries to make after that time get posted to CouchDB but the client no longer receives _changes so any new data after that point is not seen unless I reload the page.  I have searched for an answer but have not found anything that has helped.

I'm also not seeing any errors in the couch.log file.  Any suggestions or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Mind the version of CouchDB that you are using. SSL started to work from the 1.1.0 version.

> CouchDB now natively supports SSL from version 1.1.0 and onwards,
>   assuming your underlying Erlang/OTP install supports it.

[How to enable SSL](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/How_to_enable_SSL)